# jquery scrollify scrolls back to top very fast when you get to the bottom

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, jquery-scrollify

I'm using jquery scrollify on my angular application. I'm having a ton of issues as it is and the docs don't provide much help. Simply put, when I get to the bottom of my app, the app quickly scrolls back to the top for no apparent reason. Majority of the issues logged aren't answered. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I have a set of cards iterated thru an ng-repeat and I've applied the following scrollify to have them scroll and snap. If you're in the middle of the app and you refresh the app, the scrollify breaks

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $.scrollify({
        section: ".card",
        sectionName: false,
        scrollSpeed: 700,
        offset: -70,
        interstitialSection: ".card, .flow-header"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Selecting all .cards to scroll, while also selecting all .scroll to be a interstitialSection, you might break the function.

interstitialSection should probably be target specific, and not include every element. Right now, all elements are being forced full height, while you also force them to not be full height.

try:
setHeights: false,